# How to solve this in an efficient way (without calculators)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Solve for $x$, if
>   $$(x+4)(x+7)(x+8)(x+11)+20=0.$$

Is there an easier way to solve this than trying to multiply all the values together? I've tried multiplying all of them together, and I get an equation of the fourth degree which I find very hard to factorise. I'm hoping there is an easier way to solve this question. Any help is appreciated.Thanks :).

The equation I get after multiplying is
$$x^4+30x^3+325x^2+1500x+2484=0,$$
and its roots are 
$$-6, \quad -9, \quad \frac{-15\pm\sqrt{41}}2 .$$

Comment: Rational root theorem?

Comment: Note that $x < 0$ because the result must be $-20$

Comment: It's a bit time consuming to use rational root theorem because of the large coefficients so I was looking for a faster and more efficient solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If we're looking for *integer* solutions, we can see that $x + 4$, $x + 7$, $x + 8$, and $x + 11$ must be four integers whose product is $-20$, and so each must be $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 5, \pm 10, \pm 20$. The difference between the smallest and largest factor is $(x + 11) - (x + 4) = 7$, so those two factors must be either $-5$ and $2$ or $-2$ and $5$. These values correspond to the possibilities $x = -9, -6$, and substituting gives that these are indeed solutions.

With these in hand, one can expand the quartic into standard form and divide by the linear factors $x + 6$ and $x + 9$ we now know it has, leaving a quadratic to which we may apply the quadratic formula to find the remaining roots.

Of course, most quartic polynomials are irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, and so most quartic equations cannot be solved this way.

Comment: I think that you must mean "four integers whose product is $-20$".

Comment: You're right, of course, John, thank you!

Answer (score 20):

$f(x) = (x+4)(x+7)(x+8)(x+11)+20\ $ is symmetric about the line $x = -7.5$

$y = x + 7.5$

$(y-3.5)(y-0.5)(y+0.5)(y+3.5)+20=0$

$(y^2 - 0.5^2)(y^2 -3.5^2)+20=0$

$y^4 - 12.5 y^2 + 23.0625 = 0$

Use the quadratic formula to solve for $y^2.$
The square roots of that give $y.$
And, subtract $7.5$ to get $x.$

Comment: how can you tell that the function is symmetric about x = -7.5? Does it come from the distribution of those 4 'factors' (i.e. the average of the four numbers added to each 'factor' is 7.5)?

Comment: @costrom: The average of all factors is not sufficient, but already tells you where the symmetry point lies *if* it is symmetric. You then can easily check that the individual terms are indeed symmetric around that as $4=7.5-3.5$, $11=7.5+3.5$ and $7=7.5-0.5$, $8=7.5+0.5$. Alternatively you can calculate the average of the largest with the smallest, and the second largest with the second smallest (at which point you already exhausted all of them), and notice that those averages are the same.

Answer (score 12):

Rearranging the LHS, 
$$(x+4)(x+11)(x+7)(x+8)+20=0$$
to have
$$(x^2+15x+44)(x^2+15x+56)+20=0$$
Now setting $x^2+15x=t$ gives
$$(t+44)(t+56)+20=0,$$
i.e.
$$t^2+100t+2484=0\iff (t+54)(t+46)=0$$

Now solve
$$x^2+15x=-54,-46$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be solved more easily.

(1) Let $u = x + {\small{\displaystyle{\frac{15}{2}}}}$.

(2) Replace $x$ by $u - {\small{\displaystyle{\frac{15}{2}}}}$.

(3) Group the $4$ factors in matching pairs.

(4) Expand the matched pairs.

(5) Solve for $u^2$.

(6) Solve for $u$.

(7) For each solution, set $x = u - {\small{\displaystyle{\frac{15}{2}}}}$.